# jQuery Modal and displaying different content

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Hi I'm trying to display different content in a modal depending on whats clicked. The modal works fine but I'm trying to find a more efficient way of writing the following code to display the content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#block').hasClass('block1'); {
        $('.block1').click(function(){
       modal.open({content: $("<p>display this content</p>"), width: "500px", height: "200px"});
    })
   } 

   $('#block').hasClass('block2'); {
        $('.block2').click(function(){
       modal.open({content: $("<p>has different content</p>"), width: "500px", height: "200px"});
    })
   } 

   $('#block').hasClass('block3'); {
        $('.block3').click(function(){
       modal.open({content: $("<p>and again different</p>"), width: "500px", height: "200px"});
    })
   }     


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.block').click(function(){
       var content = '';
       if($(this).hasClass('block1'))content = 'content1'
       if($(this).hasClass('block2'))content = 'content2'
       if($(this).hasClass('block2'))content = 'content3'
       modal.open({content: $("<p>" + content  + "</p>"), width: "500px", height: "200px"});
    })
});
```

Comment: I you add them an comun class like 'block' and write this:                                                                   

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.block').click(function(){
       var content = '';
       if($(this).hasClass('block1'))content = 'content1'
       if($(this).hasClass('block2'))content = 'content2'
       if($(this).hasClass('block2'))content = 'content3'
       modal.open({content: $("<p>" + content  + "</p>"), width: "500px", height: "200px"});
    })
});    it will work

Comment: Is this what the html should look like then: <div class="block block1"> ?

Comment: Working thanks! It was just missing ';' after each 'content1'